# vuforia ARCamera videobackground is black

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vuforia, assetbundle, arcamera

I have create assetbundle scene with vuforia ARCamera and an imagetarget. Now after loading the assetbundle scene, the scene is able to start with black screen. I have noticed that the ARCamera -> Camera -> BackgroundPlane->VideoMaterial(Instance) -> "Custom/VideoBackground" is not enabled. But when i enabled that manually, then the camera has enabled and showing live. Is there anyway to make that shader enabled after scene loads.

Picture-1:
[Before enabling and scene was opened from assetbundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HmdG.png)

Picture-2: [After enabling shader option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwLx1.png)

Comment: in your VuforiaConfiguration settings is "Disable Vuforia Play Mode" disabled and set to your desired Webcam?

Comment: Yes, the option was disabled and set to my webcam but no luck...

Comment: Do you get any errors from Unity? Is it able to aquire and start the camera? maybe some other process is currently accessing and blocking the camera?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Senbazuru , I'm not getting any errors. The scene loading is clean and no other process is accessing the camera.

Comment: Just for my clarity, "custom/VideoBackground is not enabled" is this a gameobject, component or a property? Maybe you could provide a screenshot of the gameobject you're having trouble with?

Comment: Yes @remy_rm, I have added the pictures. Please see

Comment: I see, you should be able to fix this by attaching a script to that gameobject that searches for the VideoMaterial component and sets the shader using `yourVideoMaterial.material.shader = Shader.find("Custom/VideoBackground")` more info you can find in the docs here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-shader.html . I currently don't have to time to write an elaborate/complete answer, but hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you @remy_rm, that worked...In addition to that I found that we should add the shader in Edit->Project Settings->Graphics->Always Included Shaders->Add the shader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more complete answer for future reference:

You can solve this issue by attaching to script to said GameObject that enables the shader upon awake, it would look something like this:

```
void Awake()
{
   //get your video material component
   VideoMaterial myVideoMaterial = getComponent<VideoMaterial>();

   //Look for a shader called "VideoBackground" and apply it to the shader material of the component
   myVideoMaterial.material.shader = Shader.find("Custom/VideoBackground");

   Destroy(this);//this will remove this script after executing it, just looks a bit cleaner in my opinion but no necessary
}
```

- More information about material shaders can be found in the unity docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-shader.html).
- More information about Shader.find can be found in the docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.Find.html)

This is assuming that you have a reference to the shader from a material already somewhere in your scene. If you do not you can as per Gowthy's comment add the shader to the "always included shaders" list. This can be found by going to the `Graphics` menu under Project Settings, and then scroll down to the "Always Included Shaders" section. Or you can add the shader to a "Resources" folder that gets included in the player build"

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the Vuforia folder from the assets directory.
2. Open player settings and uncheck Vuforia support from XR settings.
3. Choose the remove files options.
4. Then check the Vuforia support again.
5. Choose Vuforia camera in your scene.
6. Add the license key.
7. That's it.